# How to getElementsByTagName and then use onmouseover when hovering a selected tag?

Tags: javascript

Sorry but I'm having trouble getting this logic to work, I want to select all `<a>` tags on the page and then log out when one of these tags are hovered over, can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

**JS**

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

links.onmouseover = function() {
    console.log('hovered');
};
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AK8N8/

//Switching to jQuery I can do this fine but would like to know the JS version

```
var links = $('a');

links.on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('hovered');
});
```

Comment: Yeah? I dont seem to see any logs when I hover on mac chrome

Comment: Oh just got what you are trying to say here, my bad

Comment: Do you need jsfiddle.net/AK8N8/1/?

Comment: ahhh ok, so I should have used the document instead. thanks!!

Comment: yap, didn't knew what you were after, so commented

Answer (score 1):

You have to add event to each element NOT to COLLECTION in pure JS. jQuery do this in the hood. So:

```
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
   // ... links[i].addEventListener()
}
```

Comment: could you help me out? I've updated my code to loop through the a tags and add the onmouseover but i'm not sure i've done this right http://jsfiddle.net/AK8N8/15/

Answer (score 1):

That's because document.getElementsByTagName returns a NodeList. You have to loop over the items and attach the onmouseover function individually:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onmouseover = function() {
        console.log('hovered');
    };
}
```